# Multiple values in a hash for a single key

Tags: perl, select, hash

I have two files.
One composed of a unique list while the other one is a redundant list of name with the age.

for example

```
File1:      File2:
Gaia        Gaia 3
Matt        Matt 12
Jane        Gaia 89
            Reuben 4
```

My aim is to match File1 and File2 and to retrieve the highest age for each name.
So far I have written the below code.
The bit that do not work quite well is: when the same key is found in the hash, print the bigger value.

Any suggestion/comment is welcome!

Thanks!!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open (FILE1, $ARGV[0] )|| die "unable to open arg1\n"; #Opens first file for comparison
open (FILE2, $ARGV[1])|| die "unable to open arg2\n"; #2nd for comparison

my @not_red = <FILE1>;
my @exonslength = <FILE2>;

#2)  Produce an Hash of File2. If the key is already in the hash, keep the couple key-          value with the highest value. Otherwise, next.

my %hash_doc2;
my @split_exons;
my $key;
my $value;

foreach my $line (@exonslength) {

    @split_exons = split "\t", $line;

    @hash_doc2 {$split_exons[0]} = ($split_exons[1]);

 if (exists $hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]}) {

    if ( $hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]} > values %hash_doc2) {

     $hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]} = ($split_exons[1]);

    } else {next;}
       }
   }

#3) grep the non redundant list of gene from the hash with the corresponding value

my @a =  grep (@not_red,%hash_doc2);
print "@a\n";
```

Comment: please submit the content of both input files using the code wrap

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to keep all the values? If not, you can only keep the max value:

```
@split_exons = split "\t", $line;
if (exists $hash_doc2{$slit_exons[0]}
    and $hash_doc2{$slit_exons[0]} < $split_exons[1]) {
    $hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]} = $split_exons[1];
}
```

You code does not keep all the values, either. You cannot store an array into a hash value, you have to store a reference. Adding a new value to an array can by done by `push`:

```
push @{ $hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]} }, $split_exons[1];
```

Your use of numeric comparison against `values` is also not doing what you think. The `<` operator imposes a scalar context, so `values` returns the number of values. Another option would be to store the values sorted and always ask for the highest value:

```
$hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]} = [ sort @{ $hash_doc2{$split_exons[0]} }, $split_exons[1] ];
# max for $x is at $hash_doc2{$x}[-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading in the whole of file2 into an array (which will be bad if it's big), you could loop through and process the data file line by line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open( my $nameFh, '<', $ARGV[0]);
open( my $dataFh, '<', $ARGV[1]);

my $dataHash = {};
my $processedHash = {};

while(<$dataFh>){
    chomp;
    my ( $name, $age ) = split /\s+/, $_;
    if(! defined($dataHash->{$name}) or $dataHash->{$name} < $age ){
        $dataHash->{$name} = $age
    }
}

while(<$nameFh>){
    chomp;
    $processedHash->{$_} = $dataHash->{$_} if defined $dataHash->{$_};
}

print Dumper($processedHash);
```